# The unreadable tool tip in eclipse [Windows]

Tags: eclipse, colors, themes

[image]

As you can see the tip select is unreadable becase the font color is the same as the background color of the select field. I have no idea how to fix it. I found here the resolution for Linux only :( [Im using the windows 7]. I tried to reinstall the eclipse etc but nothing helped me.

Can someone tell me how fix it?

Whats more everything is good i mean readable when im using the white [classic] theme but i really prefer the dark theme i think its better for my eyes.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I founded that changing the composition from Windows setting may help me. But what is it possible to change only the one atribute [font or highlight color] without changing the whole composition? :/